# Why I can't change from one scene to another by using SceneManager.LoadScene()?

Tags: unity, scenemanager

I made a game with two scenes and everytime I call the function `SceneManager.LoadScene()`, no matter the value, type(`string` or `int`) or mode(`single` or `additive`) of the parameters, the scene with build index 0 is always getting loaded.

[image: Code]

[image: Build Settings]

Comment: is the other scene added to the build menu?

Comment: Yep it is, with build index number 1, and when I set this scene to build index 0, it gets loaded all the time.

Comment: A screenshot of build settings and part of the code where you call this function will help us identify the problem. So, please do include them.

Comment: Ive added the screenshots, and in the code given, ive tried changing the modes and also tried with 1  and 2 as parameter, but its always the first scene that's getting loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to load `"Level 2"` but the scene name in the build settings is `Level2` (no space)

Comment: Well, it was just the typo mistake with my last try, But ive tried a lot of times with the correct spelling. But I ve solved the issue. The problem is restartTimer never gets greater then restartDelay and the if statement never gets executed. So ive decreased the restartDelay and it works just fine

Comment: You should write that as an answer then and accept it.